# preg_replace for template calling function that provides data to replace matched expression

Tags: php, templates

I have a template with the following tags to be replaced:

%www_authorList

%www_titleHome

I have a functions with the same names

```
public function authorList
{

}
public function titleHome
{

}
```

I want to search and replace tags with the text that function returns. Is it possible in php? as it is possible in perl...

my code try to replace

```
     $this->file = file_get_contents($template);
     $this->file = preg_replace("/%www_(\w+)/", "$this->$1()", $this->file);
```

in perl the following line do the same:

```
    my $libObj =  new libs;  
    $data =~ s/%www_(\w+)/$libObj->$1()/ge;
```

Comment: It's called [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) in PHP. (There also was an /eval flag in PHPs regex functions, but it had different context behaviour than Perls, so was [probably rightly] deprecated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need "double indirection" here, for example:

```
class Template
{
    public function authorList()
    {
        return 'auth';
    }
    public function titleHome()
    {
        return 'title';
    }
    public function run($text) {
        return preg_replace_callback("/%www_(\w+)/", array($this, 'replace'), $text);
    }
    protected function replace($matches) {
        return $this->{$matches[1]}();
    }
}

$t = new Template();
echo $t->run("%www_authorList and %www_titleHome"); // auth and title
```

php does have the `e` flag, but it's [discouraged and deprecated as of php 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), don't use it.